# Github Desktop Ignore Certain Folder

Tags: github

I have multiple folders in project. Need some folders to ignore in commit.
How can I ignore a folder while git push to master.

Answer (score 3):

Create or modify `.gitignore` [file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) , which should be in the root of your repo folder.
And the `/` represents a directory separator, so basically if you want to to exclude the `node_modules` directory just add the following line in your `.gitignore`:

```
/node_modules
```